# How to show an image from url in xceed grid (community edition)?

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid

How to show an image from url from external website in xceed grid community edition in WPF application?

I have tried may approaches but none work. Here is one of my attempt.

```
                    <xcdg:Column Title="ImgUrl"
                                  AllowSort="False"
                                  FieldName="ImgUrl">
                        <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image x:Name="img" Source ="{Binding}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                    </xcdg:Column>
```

Interestingly following works but binding does not work

```
                   <Image x:Name="img" Source ="http://somesite.com/image.jpg" />
```

An example will be useful.

Comment: Have you done any investigation yourself? Maybe post your XAML up till now? Showing an image from an URL in WPF is as easy as writing `<Image Source="http://www.someserver.com/myimage.png" />`.

Comment: It is in context of xceed data grid. I have tried few different approach and haven't been successful.

Comment: xceed datagrid examples all have either locally saved or database embedded image. There is no example of images over the http://. I am going through their sample set but no example of image urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that website hosting url had SSO authentication enabled and that didn't work from WPF client. WPF cannot handle SSO authentication like browser. So the problem is not related to xceed data grid instead is more of authentication related.